# Prevent ssh-keygen from including username and hostname

Tags: ssh

When I create an ssh key with ssh-keygen, it includes the username and hostname of the machine it was created on. Is there any way to avoid this? I read the manpage and didn't see anything.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The user name is a comment, you can delete it or set it with the -C option

I do not see a host name anywhere in the keys, what file are you looking at ?

```
ssh-keygen -f test -C noname

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in test.
Your public key has been saved in test.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
a8:fa:78:ea:bb:c6:70:67:4c:79:ac:0d:a7:78:5a:40 noname
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|  E              |
| .   o           |
|  . + +.         |
|   = B. S        |
|. o O..          |
| + *.            |
|  +o.            |
| oB*.            |
+-----------------+

cat test
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,6BD3B77199F57BCD0BBC4BD4D717931C  
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

> cat test.pub 
>   ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC2XiZLbaRwCZFPYUMNdzL7zCRvijpd4PaEbK4/zcXb6ns/9Eg2URJEVIDEBbKFrNnCQU48VNjiGG4yDyrn7COHLzWKgvLjraYV8gD0MnzqE52U5L85iuuhXcgVhc0i4Jqu3k4XoUNHGqtYMZstBhS39MCD2h8bkfKuz4eycWlyfKpktd8yIJjeUsV39mw7U7/qh/508RGuwriYe8AYNqgivnL0PmZaDwZGTCnEFaP0IPLbqKyFTcmSuVChmTYttE1Kcj4DNI57APaq2EzSGUNrBVGSJ7Q6KbXC4xiSF+RCDy8ruOk7hj2x2MGOwBZdvhy55kmMkhUMCC7BUcSiRA9F noname

No username or hostname in either file, test or test.pub

Comment: The comment was being set to my username@host. I didn't realize that that was the "comment". Thanks!

Comment: OK, ~/.ssh/known_hosts does track hostname and ip (of the server) as it should, which is why I asked

Comment: I would prefer to use `ssh-keygen -f amp_generic.pem -C ""` so that I do not have any name in the SSH public file

Comment: I just deleted my email at the end of test.pub, will it work?

Comment: @Cirelli94 Yes you can just manually delete the hostname at the bottom and it will work fine

Answer (score 6):

Apparently you can just delete the `username@hostname` at the end. I just tested it by removing that bit from one of the public keys in one of my server's `authroized_keys` files and it didn't seem to affect my ability to access that server with that key.

before:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB... ...Kzwaw== myUser@somehost
```

after:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB... ...Kzwaw==
```

Comment: Note that the comment (username@hostname) still remains in the private key and will appear in, for example, ssh-agent key listing. To remove the comment from both private and public keys you need to use `ssh-keygen -c -C "" -f <private key>`

Answer (score 0):

Upon investigation, it appears that the `user@hostname` is just a comment.  In trying to delete and import the key, it shows as invalid.  BUT, editing the `id_rsa.pub` and replacing `user@hostname` with `noname` worked.  This way you keep your existing pub key and no longer broadcast user/hostname to those that may inspect your key.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you wanted a "different comment" instead of "no comment" (what I searched for to find this post)...

The `user@hostname` is the default comment. You can also use `-C` to make that comment into anything you like.

For my purposes, I gave it the same name as the file, so I more easily recognize it in the API areas of sites I upload it to or so I know which key is referred to on remote servers with many keys in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I use...

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/My_key_nickname -C My_key_nickname
```

Then, `~/.ssh/My_key_nickname.pub` has `= My_key_nickname` at the end of the key line.